# How to format compressed string for data transfer

Tags: javascript, encode

I am making a mobile-app (not in the browser - so no transport layer solution), which needs to send compressed data back to the server. I have found several libraries in javascript that can compress the text well, but they all seem to output an array.

Using LZMA...

```
"Lorem ipsum sit amet decorum rex quandum et futurus..."
```

becomes

```
[93, 0, 0, 1, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 27, -54, 70, 103, 90, -14, 119, -72, 125, -122, -40, 66, 28, -27, -90, 80, 22, 44, 97, -102, -55, 19, 62, 83, -53, -64, 78, -1, 99, 100, 124, 91, -47, 58, -66, -12, -40, -18, 109, 98, 108, -31, -77, -110, 59, -33, 14, -60, -4, -20, 108, -1, -1, 18, -57, 0, 0]
```

Which is good, but now I need to encode it in a format suitable for sending as part of an HTTP request.

I would like it to somehow become a base64 string if possible as it would be easy to decode at the other end, and seems suited to the task - but I don't know how to convert a string of integers into a base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

This takes an array and returns a Base64 encoded string:

```
function(input)
    {
        var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        while (i < input.length)
        {
            chr1 = input[i++];
            chr2 = input[i++];
            chr3 = input[i++];

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2))
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            else if (isNaN(chr3))
                enc4 = 64;

            output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work if the numbers in the array are positive integers less than 256. Is that correct?

Comment: @BillyMoon Yes, but if you are only planing on supporting modern browsers you can use Alnitak's answer below.

Comment: I am not using any browser at all, as stated at the start of the question, which is why I can not use @Alnitak's answer.

Comment: @BillyMoon Ha! Yeah, sorry I *had* read that bit, but then promptly forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers:

```
var s = myArray.map(function(n) {
    return String.fromCharCode(n & 0xff);  // to fix your negative values
}).join('');

var base64 = btoa(s);
```

where `btoa` is a global function which can be [shimmed](https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js) if not present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately I am browser-less, so this won't work for me.

Comment: @BillyMoon in which case just find an off-the-shelf `btoa` implementation, e.g. https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js - NB: that version appears well suited for node.js, if that's your environment